# Horizontal line in LATEX

Tags: positioning

I want to draw a horizontal line in a LATEX file.
The starting point is at the middle of the page and the length is the half of the paperwidth.

How can this be done? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This revised version works with documentclasses that have symmetric or skewed margins.  I interpreted "middle of the page" to mean "middle of the **paper**", and not "middle of the **textblock**".

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\kern.5\paperwidth\kern-1in\kern-\hoffset\kern-\oddsidemargin%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[.5\paperwidth]{\hrulefill}}\par

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

**BOOK:**

[image]

**ARTICLE:**

[image]

Comment: (My understanding of the question) Wouldn't `\centerline{\hspace{0.5\textwidth}\makebox[.5\paperwidth]{\hrulefill}}` be closer to the OP's request ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i want the starting point of the line to be at center of the page. Obviously in your solution the starting point of the line is not at the center of the page.

Comment: @ApostolosK Sorry.  I will revise.

Comment: @ApostolosK Please see revision.

Comment: @BambOo. Your solution is very close to my request.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes. Your solution is very close to my request. I write a two column article and i want the starting point of the horizontal line to be at the start line of the second column and the end of the line  to be at the end of the second column.

Comment: @ApostolosK That is not the question you asked.  Which it is why it is the site policy that your question should be accompanied by a small self-contained code (starting with `\documentclass`, etc.) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]    
\noindent%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw(0,0)coordinate(o)--(o -| current page.east);}

New line here

\end{document}
```

> [image]